# How can i add MailSSLSocketFactory class into eclipse maven project

Tags: java

I use MailSSLSocketFactory class to send email via gmail to ignore certification.

eclipse does not find this class, i added java mail 1.5 repo, i use java 1.7

how can i add this package into my maven project in eclipse ?

i added this code

```
MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
socketFactory.setTrustedHosts(new String[] { "my-server"});
socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);
```

eclipse does not find `MailSSLSocketFactory` class.

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your `pom.xml`, then update maven project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

[SOURCE](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api/1.5.5)